# Databinding and multiple languages in the app C#

Tags: c#, data-binding, uwp, multilingual, globalization

[image]

I have a form that looks like this
there I edit the task selecected data.
So the texblock Due Date it's binding a  property.

```
<TextBlock  x:Name="DueDateTexblock" x:Uid="DueDateTexblock" Foreground="White"
                                Grid.Column="1"  FontSize="20"
                                DataContext="{Binding ElementName=task_list, 
                                Path=SelectedItem}" 
                                Text="{Binding Path=FormatDate}" >
</TextBlock>
```

And this it's the code of the property

```
 public string FormatDate
    {
        get
        {
            DateTimeOffset DueDate;
            if (DateTimeOffset.TryParse(_Date, out DueDate) == true)
            {
                return String.Format(" {0},{1} {2}", DueDate.DayOfWeek, DueDate.Day, 
                DueDate.ToString("MMM"));
            }
            return Date;
        }
    }
```

What I want it's set default values for the control before that property it's setted.
Like this but in multiple languages.
[image]

So how can I get that
I've tried with setting default values on the contructor of the object

```
      _NameTask =   String.Empty;
      _Reminder  =  String.Empty;
      _Date =       "Due Date";
      _Priority  =  String.Empty;
```

But this don't work with multiple languages.
Also I've tried with the resourses.Rsw
[image]
But this don't worked with the databinding, I mean when I bind the property just show it a empty text.

Comment: I'm confused about what's the problem. The `TextBlock ` showing Due Date is not the behavior that you want, right? Then what's the behavior you want? What's your scneario?

Comment: I want show Due date text in multiple languages when the it's not setted and when I set the due date show the date. like sun, 10, jun

Comment: Do you mean you want to show the `Due date` in different languages when there is no date selected?

Answer (score 0):

For multiple languages you should be able to use Resources like https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22420.binding-to-resources-resx-files-in-xaml.aspx
For each language you will need a .resx file.

Default language "MyLocalizations.resx" for german "MyLocalization.de.resx" for italian "MyLocalization.it.resx" and so on.

And to switch the current language you have to set the CurrentUICulture and the infrastructure should use the according .resx file.

And for formatting date time there are built in formats: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/date-and-time-format-in-c-sharp-programming1

Comment: But how can I set the default value before that i setted and then bind the property Due date that is something like sun, 17, jun

Answer (score 0):

for the people who are in the same position
this the solution that  I came up

```
 get 
        {
            if ( _NameList == string.Empty || _NameList == null)
            {
                return rm.GetDefaultNamelist;
            }
            return _NameList;

            }
        set { _NameList = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(NameList); }
```

I defined the defaults values in the resx file.

```
public class Resource_Manager
{
   
 ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("Resources", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

    public string GetDefaultDate
    {
        get =>  rm.GetString("DefaultDueDate");                   
    }

    public string GetDefaultReminder
    {
        get => rm.GetString("DefaultReminder");
    }

   public string GetDefaultNamelist
    {
        get => rm.GetString("DefaultNameList");
    }
}
```